# Flexible and dynamic web pages techniques

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, responsive-design

I have basic knowledge in html,css and good knowledge in JS. But I have problems with putting all this together. I mostly develop for `Android`, I mean native apps. I have good understanding of `Android layout`. Concept of dynamic layout is great in android, when I develop apps I try to use relative positions and dynamic sizes whenever it is possible, like `match_parent`,`wrap_content`. They are really powerful, apps looks great on any screen. Also there is such measure in android called `dp` density independent pixels. This is also great concept.

So I want to dive into web page development, but I don't know common patterns, techniques for building responsive and flexible pages.
I know a little bit about `@media` and `viewport` directives for `CSS` but I again I cannot put together all my knowledge to start building responsive web pages.
For instance is it better to use `percantage` instead of `px`, as I can see mostly `px` are used , I cannot understand this concept why not to use `percantage` everywhere to make page responsive ?

Maybe I am missing something important in web page development, so why I am asking about advice.

Please suggest maybe some good articles about current best practices for building responsive web pages(based on most popular engines Wordpress,Drupal,Joomla) or from the scratch for better understanding.
Also one important question is how to build web page mobile friendly and so on.
Thank you so much

Comment: Just a bit of friendly guidance: Stack Overflow discourages questions that seek opinions and recommendations. They are considered [**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Instead, describe the problem and what has been done to solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand this, can you suggest where to ask such kind of questions ?

Comment: Now that's a good question! :-) I myself have several questions where I would like to hear expert opinion. I don't believe Stack Exchange is the right place for that. You could go on [**Stack Overflow Meta**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to look for guidance, or post your question (from your comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to get going quickly with responsive web design, consider starting with one of the many established frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) or [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com). There are plenty of others as well.

They will save you heaps of time at the start, and you'll get good cross-browser results. Pick one you like, jump in and then learn more as you go!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To design a responsive web page  there are two option :

1) design to website one for computers and another one for mobile like facebook

2) same design

there are many techniques to responsive design :

1) you can use percentage for all your content but you must use many calculations to it

2) you can use grid system  from bootstrap

3) you can use media and smallest your content and test it by your browser like firefox for responsive design view

4) you can mix between percentage and media .

in this techniques you must to know postion and display and how its works

main divs must be in percentage  like body or main wrapper width 100% and inside divs must depends on thier width